# How to count and display the occurrence of a number in a json array of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, d3.js

Please forgive me if this is a dumb or basic question but I have not been able to find a good solution. I have a json array of numbers:

```
 [30, 37,34,56,76,87,54,34,2,4,2,5,5,3,4,3,4, 90]
```

I would like to count how many times each number occurs and use that data to produce a graph using d3js. How can I go about doing this? If there is a D3 method that does this, that would be great. But a javascript/jquery solution would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript:

```js
var items = [30, 37, 34, 56, 76, 87, 54, 34, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 90],
    histogram = items.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = (r[a] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(histogram, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the graphing, check out [c3](http://c3js.org/). This can be easily done with something like this:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            numbers.unshift('x'),
            occurrences.unshift('occurrences'),
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    } });
```

where numbers is an array of all distinct numbers and occurrences is an array of the numbers of time each occurs.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/494/)

Comment: @JET c3 is just a library on top of d3, and they are all JavaScript libraries. Reading data from external files would be just be another job that needs to be done in JavaScript.